# Creating random 1 mil records normally distributed python

Tags: python, excel

So I want to create 1 million  random records that will distribute normally.
I have 12 time spaces:

```
hours_dic = {1:"00:00-02:00",2:"02:00-05:00",3:"05:00-07:00",4:"07:00-08:00",5:"08:00-10:00",
6:"10:00-12:00",7:"12:00-16:00" ,8:"15:00-17:00",9:"17:00-19:00",10:"19:00-21:00",11:"21:00-22:00",12:"22:00-00:00"}
```

My problem is that I want the randomized records would distribute normally. Lets say that the mean is "17:00-19:00", right now the std is not important as those records are "dummy data" for a research. I would like to generate the records and later to put them in EXCEL.

To clarify, those hours represent using time, and I want to generate the data with the assumption that the majority use the app at the afternoon.

I thought about using numpy:

```
x = np.random.normal(loc=9,scale=1,size=1000000)
```

And then maybe using .map with the hours_dic.

However, I can't find a way to make the generated number integers only (as I want to use the dictionary)    and to ensure the distribution is as I wanted.

Thanks for any help, if any elaboration is required please ask.
(If there's an Excel solution I'd like to know it too)

Comment: call `x.astype(int)`

Comment: As easy as that. Thanks!
Yet, is there any effective way I can take those records created and put them in 1 column in an excel file?

Comment: Look at openpyxl.

Comment: Too bad there's no Close reason "answered in comments."

Comment: Thanks it seems good.
However I encountered another problem with the generation.
As I said, I need the values to be from 1 to 12, generating like I did  generates  numbers bigger than 12 (up to 14 actually), couldn't find how restrict it